# Loop over decimals in R

Tags: r, loops, decimal

I've got a simple question that's stumping me. I'm trying to use a loop to count how many values of a vector fall in a bin (0,.01), (.01,.02), etc. For example (the loop does not work):

```
set.seed(12345)
x<- rnorm(100, 0, .05)
vec <- rep(NA, 11)

for(i in .01:.11){
vec[i] <- sum(x> i & x < (i +.01))
}
```

I would like this to ultimately produce a vector of the count between each break, such that the output for the above is:

```
5,9,10...
```

I think this may have something to do with the indexing/decimals. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Your problem has everything to do with `.01:.11`. Run just that snippet and see if it's what you want... with non-integers you need to use `seq` or `(1:11) / 100`. (Of course, the answer with `cut` is better than a `for` loop anyway.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You example contains negative numbers so I assume you are looking to do this with positive numbers. You should use `cut` to divide your vector into the given bins by setting `breaks` parameter. Then using `table` you can compute frequencies of x's falling within each interval.

```
## filter x 
x <- x[x>=0.01] ## EDIT here : was  x <- abs(x)
res <- table(cut(x,breaks=seq(round(min(x),2),round(max(x),2),0.01)))
## prettier output coerce to data.frame
as.data.frame(res)

#           Var1 Freq
# 1  (0.01,0.02]    5
# 2  (0.02,0.03]    9
# 3  (0.03,0.04]   10
# 4  (0.04,0.05]   10
# 5  (0.05,0.06]    4
# 6  (0.06,0.07]    0
# 7  (0.07,0.08]    5
# 8  (0.08,0.09]    2
# 9   (0.09,0.1]    5
# 10  (0.1,0.11]    4
# 11 (0.11,0.12]    1
```